# find all lines in a file with number range

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I have text as below in a file.

```
abcdxyz Time(0.010),blah blah blah
abcdxyz Time(1.010),blah blah blah
abcdxyz Time(0.010),blah blah blah
abcdxyz Time(2.010),blah blah blah
abcdxyz Time(3.010),blah blah blah
abcdxyz Time(8.010),blah blah blah
```

I want to grep all lines where value in `Time()` is greater than `2.00`. How can I do this in ksh.

FYI: my OS is Red hat linux and I am using ksh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `awk`

```
awk -F'[()]' '$2>2{print}' file
```

Output:

```
abcdxyz Time(2.010),blah blah blah
abcdxyz Time(3.010),blah blah blah
abcdxyz Time(8.010),blah blah blah
```

Comment: Nothing more to add, perfect solution for the task. +1

Comment: how can I sort this output in descending order of time??

Comment: @user2859999 Try `sort -nr -t'(' -k2` on output with pipe `|`

Answer (score 0):

This works (on a AIX/ksh)

```
sed 's/\(.*\)Time(\(.*\))\(.*\)/\2 \1Time(\2)\3/' a.dat | awk '{ if ($1 > 2.0) { $1="" ;  print } }'
```

Comment: This is really terrible :-)